# check only one checkbox in gridview using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have a grid view in which i have placed the checkbox in itemtemplate

i want only the one checkbox is selected from Gridview to select that perticular row so that i can use that id to edit or delete the row

aspx page code is

```
            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Select
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Branch Name
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBranch_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Branch") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Address
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    City
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
```

and i want when i click on the checkbox which is at first of each row only one check box is selected from all the rows

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do like this.....with single check box selection using jquery....

ASPX CODE

```
<table id="GirdViewTable">
<tr>
<td>
<asp:GridView ID="gvLeave" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="Col2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" Height="100%" PageSize="25" Width="100%">
<RowStyle CssClass="Col1" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="TdTitle" ForeColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="leaveName" HeaderText="Leave" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="leaveCode" HeaderText="Code" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="days" HeaderText="Days" />
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkLeave" runat="server" onclick="toggleSelectionGrid(this);" />
<asp:Label ID="lblLeaveID" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("leaveID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="Col2" />
</asp:GridView>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Bind Grid

```
private void BindLeaveMaster()
{
     DataTable dt = HREmpLeave.GetSearch(null, null, null, null, true, null, null, null, null).Tables[0];
     try
     {
          if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
               gvLeave.DataSource = dt;
               gvLeave.DataBind();
          }
          else
          {
               gvLeave.DataSource = null;
               gvLeave.DataBind();
          }
     }
     catch (Exception oException)
     {
           oException.Message.ToString();
     }
     finally
     {
          dt = null;
    }
}
```

Page_Load

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{ 
      BindLeaveMaster();
}
```

JQuery Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-1.5.1min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function toggleSelectionGrid(source) 
{
   var isChecked = source.checked;
   $("#GirdViewTable input[id*='chkLeave']").each(function(index) {
   $(this).attr('checked', false);
});
  source.checked = isChecked;
}

</script>
```